# DIfference between value and reference types in .NET

Tags: .net, types, garbage-collection

I have a tiny problem in understanding the difference between reference and value types in the .net framework. You might say this is a foundamental difference that every programmer is supposed to know, and I believed to know this difrference, but it happens, sometimes, that in some books there are different conceptions of this issue.

I know that .NET is a managed environment where a garbage collector exists and operates. Data and structures are stored in two main locations: the managed **heap** and the **stack**.

The managed heap should act as a container for all pointers to real data that reside in stack. This is what I know and what was explained in a book regarding .NET by Dino Esposito (talking about vb.net).
Is this so? Or there is something not correct??

I also have another question...
Or better I need a confirm to my ideas...

When I write something like this in c#

```
string mystring = "Hello World!";
```

I suppose that CLR creates a string data in stack and creates a pointer to that data in the heap.
If I do so:

```
mynamespace.someprintfunction(mystring);
```

What happens is that CLR retrieves "Hello World!" by looking into mystring (a pointer in the heap to a data in the stack).

Furthermore, given that string is immutable, if I do so:

```
string mystring2 = "Hello World!";
```

CLR does not creates a new pointer mystring2 in the heap and a record for "Hello World!" in the stack, but it uses the pre-existing "Hello World!" pointed by mystring and creates a new pointer to it.
Result is that mystring and mystring2 points to the same location in the stack.

Comment: The difference between value and reference types is **not** where they are stored. Stupid urban myth. See e.g. [Eric Lippert's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx).

Comment: You are more like answering a question than asking a question.

Comment: I think you have the stack and the heap mixed up in the latter part of your question.

Comment: IMO, heap/stack does not define what value/reference means.  Value and reference are defined by their behavior when you use them.  If the heap/stack metaphor helps you understand it, that's great, but it if confuses you, forget about it until it matters (which is probably never if you're making a standard LOB CRUD application).

Comment: Yeah I am sorry I know it's more like an answer than a question... I am trying to see if what I think is the same in the real world :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing heap and stack. If you create an instance of a reference type, usually the memory for this class is allocated on the heap, and on your stack you get a reference / pointer to that data.

About the difference between value and reference types, some say value types are stored on the stack and reference types on the heap, but that's not always true (also, it's an implementation detail of the CLR and in most cases should not matter for the user).

The most important difference is, that value types are passed *by value* (you copy the whole data into another variable when assigning), and reference types *by reference* (you only copy a reference to the original data).

so when you do `int x = 5; int y = x;`, you are copying the value of x. x and y do not refer to the same data. 
on the other hand, if you do the same with instances of reference types, both variables refer to the same object.

Comment: Thank you Botz3000... I did confuse stack and heap that's why things got coumbersome at certain ponts when reading articles and so on...

Comment: Would you mind editing this to say "reference types have their references passed by value" or something along those lines? I know you clarify in the parenthesis, but particularly because of the ref keyword it pays to be extra-clear. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Not all the so called "Real Data" resides on the stack.
For example:

```
public static void Main()
{
   int a = 5;
   int[] arr = new int[20];
}
```

`a` is a value type and its 4 bytes are on the stack while `arr` is a pointer to a heap allocated memory, `arr` itself (the pointer) is on the stack but the actual array data (even though it is an integer's array) is being allocated on the heap.

**Edit**
about your second question.
1. string literals are being saved in a special locations so the two strings variables will point to the same object.
When you do `string mystring = "Hello World!";` mystring will point to the string literal and when calling the method the pointer to the string will be pushed to the stack as a method parameter.

Comment: Thank you Italy... well I did confuse it... so itwas the opposite... thank you.... I am sorry but Botz3000 arrived first and I had to give him the correct answer...